# Dropbox auto authenticate using core APi

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to avoid a user to login from browser right now the code looks like this.
Want to avoid login screen mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(this); -- this will kick off login i have removed this and hard coded token key and token secret key

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        checkAppKeySetup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.Error("onCreate", e);
    }
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Dropbox
    AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();
    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Mandatory call to complete the auth
            session.finishAuthentication();
            // Store it locally in our app for later use
            TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
            setLoggedIn(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:"
                            + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Logger.Error("onCreate", e);
        }
        Log.i("On resume method", "authentication was active");
    }
}

private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session;
    String[] stored = getKeys();
    if (stored != null) {
        AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0],
                stored[1]);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE,
                accessToken);
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);
    }


private String[] getKeys() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "XXXXXXXX");
    String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, "xxxxxxx");
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        String[] ret = new String[2];
        ret[0] = key;
        ret[1] = secret;
        return ret;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

session.authenticationSuccessful() returns false always and i am not able to upload a file to dropbox. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this:

```
// OAUTH_TOKEN and OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET are the hardcoded credentials you want to use
mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(new AndroidAuthSession(
    new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET), ACCESS_TYPE,
    new AccessTokenPair(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)));
```

But ***I strongly advise against this approach***. If you hardcode an OAuth token for your account, then anyone who has your app will be able to extract the token and then delete all your files, use your account to share illegal content, etc. In short, it's a very bad idea.

The typical use of the Dropbox API is to have each user use their own account with your app.

Comment: thank you so much and sorry for the late reply. How can i get my oauth key and oauth secret key?

Comment: You have a line in your code above `storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);`. `tokens.key` and `tokens.secret` are the OAuth token and secret.